# Tracking the location of a file in C# windows?

Tags: c#, file

I need to track the location of some files that i know the initial full paths. Situtation as follows :
I have a file in path C:\Temp\first.txt
in some time this first.txt file changes location to for example C:\Temptwo folder

i need to learn this second location automatically when the location change happens is there way to do it in C# thanks.

Comment: How do you expect the user to send the file? What does "send" mean?

Comment: It's not possible for all ways a user can interact with files.

Comment: for example user has file in C:\\Temp\\A.txt then sends file to C:\\Temptwo\\ directory program will inititialized in clients computer as service when this operation happens this service needs to know new location for the file our you can think it as not client but my own computer too same principle

Comment: Send by email or how? There are so many ways to get a file to that location...

Comment: You dont seem to understand my question at all I am going to edit my question with details so please read again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand your question. But think of this: you put the file C:\\Temp\\A.txt into an email. You send the email to yourself. You then delete the file C:\\Temp\\A.txt. You open the email received by yourself and save the attachment to C:\\Temptwo\\ How would anyone be able to detect that? There may be days between those operations.

Comment: Another way: the user copies the file C:\\Temp\\A.txt to C:\Desktop\B.txt, then deletes C:\\Temp\\A.txt and then copies C:\Desktop\B.txt to C:\\Temptwo\\

Comment: Third way: user creates C:\\Temptwo\\A.txt first, then opens C:\\Temp\\A.txt. He copies all the text into the clipboard. He closes the file and deletes it. Then opens C:\\Temptwo\\A.txt again and pastes all content from the clipboard.

Comment: Why do you need to track its location? And why do you want to allow the user to move it?

Comment: Xerillio i am creating a system where user gonna select somefile to be backup in periods a service will run all the time when computer is running i am going to take paths of files but if place of file changes i need to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where the files are moving from and to. If you are moving from `C:\\MyProgram\TempA\Temp.txt` to `C:\\MyProgram\TempB\Temp.txt`, then you can just use the directory tools. `Directory.GetFiles` will scan a directory for you and return an array of strings containing the names of those files. If you know the name of the file you are looking for, or you are using a unique file extension, then you can search through the files you find until you identify the file you are looking for. You can also call `Directory.GetDirectories` recursively to look through sub-directories if you have a lot of folders this file could be hiding in.

While this might technically work on the C drive, I would suggest carefully considering your use case before trying to re-invent Windows Search.

Comment: How do i know for sure that Temp.txt is the Temp.txt from TempA and not a different txt file with Temp name ?

Comment: You could use [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0) as a point of comparison. Much of the metadata will remain the same, even if the file is moved or renamed.

Comment: Another option might be to look at Git. It's open sourced, so you can see how they solve this problem. If you create a file, commit the file, then rename or move it AND modify its contents, Git will compare the deleted file to the newly added file and try to determine what happened. I think that they look at the file contents to determine if it is the same file as before. If you want a better answer, I'd suggest adding the detail that you are creating a backup utility to your question. Those kind of details can get you a lot more useful of an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will look up more detailed thanks.